# dev packages not getting included in Yocto SDK

Tags: package, sdk, yocto, bitbake

We are generating Yocto SDK using the following command: `bitbake -c populate_sdk <image-name>`

Yocto Branch : Dunfell

We don't see header files getting included in the SDK, for example we have libmodbus part of `IMAGE_INSTALL`, but we don't see the `modbus.h` file (which is present in libmodbus-dev package) in SDK.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you execute the command below so we can verify your setup:

```
bitbake -e <image-name> | grep SDKIMAGE_FEATURES
```

Development packages are automatically included into SDK when they are installed into the image when SDKIMAGE_FEATURES variable defines it

```
SDKIMAGE_FEATURES = "dev-pkgs staticdev-pkgs"
```

https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.1/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#var-SDKIMAGE_FEATURES

Comment: Berndll - I add the `libpam` library into my image SDK file system for 64&32 bit versions (i.e. - `libpam` and `lib32-libpam`). I achive that by adding the `MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"` "feature". One of the symbolic links of the `lib32-libpam` belongs to the `lib32-libpam-dev` package, so I added the line you wrote in your answer. For the 64 bit, the `libpam-dev` was installed - HOWEVER, the `lib32-libpam-dev` is still NOT installed. Is there anything I should do in addition? I take the libpam recipes from Yocto thus don't have control of them (if I do need to have, please indicate).